# Would anyone know of a book with a proof for the HNN extension which is purely algebraic in it?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, reference-request

Would anyone know of a book with a proof for why you HNN extension which is purely algebraic in it? I understand that proofs for it usually involve topology, and I haven't done any topology.

By this, I mean a proof for why you can apply the HNN extension to any group G with isomorphic subgroups A and B to get a group G* such that G is a subgroup of G* and A and B are conjugate in G. Why does this work for all such groups G, A and B?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "a proof for the HNN extension".

Comment: Rotman's "Introduction to the Theory of Groups", 4th Edition, has a proof (Theorem 11.70) and a section on it; it connects it to topology later and I haven't chased down everything they are doing, but looking through it quickly it looks like an algebraic proof.

Answer (score 5):

If you will excuse me suggesting a book of which I am co-author, there is an algebraic proof  in Section 1.5.15, pages 16 - 19 of

Groups, Languages and Automata,
Derek F. Holt, Sarah Rees and Claas E. Röver,
LMS Student Texts 88, CUP 2017.

The main result is Proposition 1.5.17, which establishes a normal form for elements of the HNN extension using coset representatives of the subgroups $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the [book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=aiPVBygHi_oC&pg=PA1&hl=nl&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Roger Lyndon & Paul Schupp, C*ombinatorial Group Theory* (1977), also provides an algebraic proof in Chapter 4.

D.J.S. Robinson's [book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=zLfkBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Robinson%20a%20course%20in%20the%20theory%20of%20groups&hl=nl&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Robinson%20a%20course%20in%20the%20theory%20of%20groups&f=false), *A Course in the Theory of Groups*, Embedding Theorems 6.4.5 also has one.